# MIPS32 word array

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, segmentation-fault, mips32

I'm trying to translate a simple C function (that tells you whether a word, made by a char array, is a palindrome) into MIPS 32 but I'm having trouble using getting to load non-multiple-of-4 positions of the array.

Apparently,

```
`li  t0,0(a0)`
```

loads the first letter (char), and

```
`li  t0,4(a0)`
```

loads the fifth letter of the array (I thought it would have been the second one). Trying to load the second, as in:

```
`li  t0,1(a0)`
```

gets me a segmentation fault. So does using shift left logical before loading 0(a0). How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, here's how I got it to work:

```
addu  a0,a0,t0    #t0 = i, a0 <- a0+i
lb    t2,0(a0)    #store array[i] in t2
subu  a0,a0,t0    #returns a0 to original value
```

If I want to get to the second letter, I load 1 in t0, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a 32-bit platform and it requires aligned access.  So if `a0` is aligned to 4 bytes, then `li t0,0(a0)` will load the first 32-bit value of `a0` into `t0`.  But `li t0,1(a0)` will try (and fail) to load a misaligned 32-bit value.

So don't try to load one character at a time.  Embrace the fact that MIPS 32 will load 4 characters (32 bits) at a time.  You can access single characters within a word using shift and bitwise-and.

Comment: Thanks for answering, can you give me an example on how you would retrieve the second character within the word?